# Search drop down list from mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

I have the following in my data

```
Year Week
2011 19
2011 18
2011 17
2012 1
```

I have created a drop down list form for display the info

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getWeek()
{
    if (document.getElementById('y').value != '')
    {
        document.getElementById('d').disabled = ''; // this will enable the select
    }
}
</script>
<form name="myform" action="http://www.website.com/displaybook.php" method="get">
<select size="1" name="y" id ="y" onchange="getWeek()"> 
<?
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (Year) FROM data ORDER BY Year Desc");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<option value='". $row['Year']."'>Season - ". $row['Year']."</option>";
}

?>  
</select>
<select size="1" name="d" id="d" disabled="disabled"> 
<?
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT (Week) FROM data ORDER BY Week ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<option value='". $row['Week']."'>Week - ". $row['Week']."</option>";
}
?>  
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Get data">
</form>
```

My problem is that i want it to display for example only week of 2012 when selected 2012 and week 2011 when selected 2011 etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<option value='". $row['Year']."'>Season - ". $row['Year']."</option>";
}
```